# Fangate after "like" needs refresh, but only on some computers

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

our fangate is working perfectly here in our office on safari, chrome or firefox,
but OF COURSE, not on the customers computer, neither chrome nor firefox nor safari.

So we looked via teamviewer whats going on in his environment, and we saw in firebug
that facebook is going to fire a post after the click on "like" which results in "404"

```
http://www.facebook.com/ajax/pages/fetch_app_column.php?__a=1&__user=XXX&fb_dtsg=AQBzGDeE&phstamp=165816612271681016991&profile_id=XXX&tab_key=app_XXX
```

Did anyone encoutered this problem?

Comment: I am seeing this bug now. Whats the reason.

Comment: There's an answer on here that might solve the problem, about forcing a reload after the page is Liked: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7519219/205245

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, bugs like these crop up often with Facebook and to make things worse they exist for days at a time on some or all of their servers, this means that some users get errors and some it works fine for.

Recently we have seen this fangate issue for a number of days before they fixed it. If you can't find the bug listed on their systems I would register it as soon as possible. http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/